# Contextual Filters Help - User Pages

Tags: views

I am working with user pages and I have styled a user page with a custom .tpl and I am using a block to bring in the latest post from that user using views. I am having a problem sorting out the posts with contextual filters. I have set up the contextual filter to work if the URL was /user-name but because it is a users page the URL is /users/user-name and this is screwing up my filter. Any advice someone can give me?

Answer (score 2):

I usually add a contextual filter for "user: uid", specify a default of "userid from the URL" and then set a validation criteria for "user" and "Allow both numeric UIDs and string usernames".
That way you can use both the uid and the username.

You'll probably have your "last post block" show up on the profile edit page because it's at "user/%/edit".
I changed my user profile pages to "member/USERNAME" using the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.